# Microphone and speaker doesn't working in Lenovo ThinkPad t440 version of Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: 22.04, microphone, 20.10, 23.04

In my Lenovo ThinkPad t440, the latest version of Ubuntu 2023 is not working with microphone and Speaker can anyone clarify my issue